# Error Redeploying in WLST only

Tags: weblogic

I have a very odd error which I am unable to solve.

I have an enterprise application. The build ear file deploys successfully using either WLST or the weblogic Deployer command line too.

The webapp is versioned using  "Weblogic-Application-Version" in the Manifest.mf file.

However, when I go to redeploy the EAR using the WLST command "redeploy(...)" I get the below error

> java.io.IOException: java.io.CharConversionException: Malformed UTF-8 char -- is an XML encoding declaration missing?Failed to redeploy the application with status failed

The strange thing is that if I use the command line deployer, "java weblogic.Deployer -redeploy..." the ear file redeploys perfectly fine.

Also if I use the deploy command "deploy(....)" it also deploys successfully, and retires the old version.

Ideally I'd like to use the redeploy command in WLST to ensure the old version retires correctly.

1. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be causing this problem?
2. When weapps are versioned, does deploy(...) do the same thing as redeploy(...) in wlst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out what was happening here, so I'm going to post it here in case anyone has the same issue.

I was using the wlst command:

```
redeploy(<app-name>, <app-path>....)
```

Where  was the location of the ear file. This isn't correct as the second argument should be the plan path (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13813/reference.htm#WLSTC222)

I switch to using name arguments along the lines of

```
redeploy(appName=<app-name>, appPath=<appPath>, ...)
```

which worked successfully. The error message was extremly unhelpful.